# Home page active class can not removed

Tags: jquery

I am creating task in which when website load the home page menu is active and after when click on another page it will remove and add active class to other menu. My JS runs but it can not remove active class of home menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var url = window.location;
  $('ul.navbar-nav a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('active');
  $('ul.navbar-nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
  }).addClass('active');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo/logo 2.png" class="logo" /></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.php">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="photo.php">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I dont see any `.removeClass()` so that might be the reason why. Maybe try `$('ul.navbar-nav a').removeClass('active')`

Comment: i add this but when i open website home menu is not active

Comment: initially when i open website , home menu is active, Due to this line $('ul.navbar-nav a').removeClass('active') it will remove active tag on website load

Comment: You must add event handler in the loop. For all the links ... You simply want the clicked link to have the active class and all other links should not have the active class. RIght.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather how plz change in code

Comment: Give me a momemt ! Please :)

Comment: Try changing `href="index.php"` to `href="/"`. Will match home page then

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Yes i need help ..

Comment: Dear Seema Patil, I would love to help you. The issue is I don't work on PHP. I am a react developer. I had provided the logic to put active class on the current link. But Mr.Charlietfl didn't agreed with my logic. Did you tried my logic before I deleted my answer ?

Comment: Is what charlietlf commented above not working for you. Like he wants the href="/" in your code.

Comment: @charlietfl not working for me it will redirect to xampp home page

Comment: What is url of your home page when you open in xampp?

Comment: @charlietfl            localhost:81/paintservices/